# Inverter voltage conversion

Tags: inverter, voltage-measurement

I have a 24 Vdc battery that I have connected to an inverter to. Using the Vrms to Vac equation (i.e. multiplying by sqrt(2)) I would find the peak value of the Vac. So it would be 34.0 Vac. My question is that if I could make that Vac value lower instead of being 34.0 Vac by the inverter. I am looking to convert 24 Vdc to 24 Vac. Is that possible?

Comment: do you want "24V AC" i.e. 24V RMS? That would be about 34V peak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, unless otherwise indicated, `34 Vac` means `the RMS voltage of the AC voltage is 34 V` or simply `34 Vrms`. If you mean the peak value of the AC voltage then you should say `34 Vpk` because the peak is not an AC *(i.e. peak does not change with time -- it's an instantaneous value)*.

So,

> I am looking to convert 24Vdc to 24Vac.

You already have 24 Vac, and its peak value is 34V.

---

If you want to have a `24Vpk / 17Vrms` AC voltage then the easiest way, assuming the voltage is a 50- or 60-Hz-sine and replacing the entire inverter is not an option, is to use a step-down transformer with a turn ratio of 17 / 24 = 0.71.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 24Vdc battery that I have connected to an inverter to. Using the Vrms to Vac equation(ie multiplying by sqrt(2)) I would find the peak value of the Vac.

What Vac?

> So it would be 34.0 Vac.

You seem to have assumed a 24 VAC RMS here, and converted it to 34 V peak.

> My question is that if I could make that Vac value lower instead of being 34.0 Vac by the inverter.

If the inverter is specified to generate a 24 VRMS sinewave, then we *could* also express that as 34 V peak, but we rarely do. It's standard to express Vac as the RMS value.

An inverter that generates a mangled sinewave (cheaper ones do) would not have a 1.414 ratio between peak and rms.

You could use a transformer with a suitable ratio, or maybe the inverter can be programmed to deliver a lower voltage.

> I am looking to convert 24Vdc to 24Vac. Is that possible?

Yes. It's certainly possible. Make sure you are clear what that Vac specification means (is it RMS or peak?, both for your requirement, and for the inverter), and then choose an inverter that gives that, program an inverter that you have to give that, or follow an inverter with a suitable transformer to give that.